# How do I give each user different form in Django formset?

Tags: python, django

So, I'm trying to give each user his/her own form in Django. I'm giving users same question, and trying to let them input their own answers in `modelformset_factory`. First let me show you my code. (I'll skip the codes regarding question model, since the problem is in the answer form.)

 models.py

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    authuser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    questionNumber = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

forms.py

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.CharField(max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        model=Answer
        fields=['answer',]
```

```
def answerSheet(request): 
    AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AnswerForm, extra=1)
    formset = AnswerFormSet(initial=[
        {
            'authuser':request.user
            }
        ])
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

            return redirect('index')

    context = {
        'formset':formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'formset/index.html', context)
```

I figured `initial = [{'authuser':request.user}]` part will do what I intended, but apparently it doesn't. What I get instead is the same accumulated answers in formset, regardless of which user I log into. What I want, again, is to have different formset to different users.
What do you think is the problem? Thank you very much in advance. :)

Comment: I think you need to filter rather than initial. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks. But can I filter forms as well? Not model?